# How can I unclog a bathroom sink overflow port?

Tags: bathroom

I have a bathroom sink overflow that has been clogged for over 20 years! I realized I need it to have it working properly so I have been trying to open  it up.

I have tried using CLR and the sharp end of a coat hanger wire but no go. Is there a small snake or tool that can be attached to a drill to bore out the clog? I don't know what other chemicals I could use. Thanks

Comment: How do you feel about accessing it from beneath?

Comment: None of bathroom sinks in our house have overflows and we have yet to have a sink overflow in the 12 years I've had the house, even with 4 kids growing up there.  Can't say that will apply to all kids though.

Comment: The regular "Drain" is fine. I just want to unclog the overflow. I COULD remove the Post up drain but I would rather not. Its just every time I clean the sink, water and cleanser gets into the overflow and black muck comes out!   Thanks!

Comment: Is this a cast iron porcelain lavatory? Pure china all the way through? Do you have any idea what the nature of the clogging material is? The reason I ask is that the cast iron one is going to be pretty resistant to impact damage, but the china one could be cracked. You could chuck up a length of coat hanger wire in a cordless drill and see if you could bore through the blockage.

Comment: This is a American Standard Cast iron sink. It was installed in 1959. It does have porcelain overlay as most sinks do. ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have tried to use a coat hanger wire with a sharp edge on it. All the muck has stopped coming out. I believe I have a solid blockage. I don't think its worth any more trouble at this point. I do not want to remove the pop-up drain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a plunger to seal over the overflow hole, you might be able to force some air in there, or vacuum some air out, and dislodge the clog.

These things are very inexpensive and might work where the wire hanger did not.  Some are more flexible, some are pretty stiff.  You might also try a flat steel drain snake, just be careful and don't apply too much force.

[image: zip-it]

Answer (score 0):

I have not had much luck cleaning bathroom sinks from the top, I have found it ends up being much easier to pull the drain and work from the bottom where the overflow enters. All the gunk is usually packed at the bottom and in 1 case the solid section of the drain was partially blocking the overflow, I would not have found that if I did not pull the drain. Depending on how the drain is sealed you may need some fresh plumbers putty to seal it back up but if an o ring they can usually be cleaned and reused if in good shape.